# Android HorizontalScrollView nesting HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I want to have a HorizontalScrollView containing a HorizontalScrollView.

This is my current Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.erik.playground.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                app:cardElevation="9dp"
                android:layout_width="500dp"/>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        app:cardElevation="9dp"
                        android:layout_width="600dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>


    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Right now the inner HorizontalScrollView does not scroll and only the outer one scrolls.

Is there a possibility to make that work?

Comment: Why ? Can you simply put multiple view in your horizontalScrollView ?

Comment: In the end the outer one will be paged and the inner one is the content of one page. I know that you can use a pager for that but i want to port that to react native with that it would be way easier doing it without a pager.

Comment: Have you thought about a simple RecyclerView scrolling horizontal ?

Comment: For that you will need an Adapter and everything is getting complicated.

Comment: Did you found a solution to your problem ?

Comment: In the end i just used a ViewPager.